# Why are values being truncated while reading an Excel 2007 (.xlsx) file in Perl?

Tags: perl, excel

I am reading an `.xls` file using [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) and was able to get data as is.

But,when reading an `.xlsx` file using [Spreadsheet::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Spreadsheet::XLSX), the read values are truncated.

E.g., `2.4578` in `.xls` and `.xlsx` file is read as `2.4578` and `2.45`, respectively.

Please suggest why `.xlsx` file data is corrupted.

Comment: Provide an example spreadsheet file and show your code; these will help much in order to give you an exact answer.

Answer (score 3):

I created a simple workbook containing one sheet and only the value `2.4578` in `A1` and ran the following script:

```
use Spreadsheet::XLSX;

my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX->new('Book1.xlsx');

my ($sheet) = @{ $excel->{Worksheet} };

print $sheet->{Cells}[0][0]{Val}, "\n";
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> x
2.4578000000000002
```

So, in this simple case, everything seems to be OK.

If you can post a short, self-contained example that exhibits the problem and a small sample `.xlsx` file which we can look at, we would have a better chance of identifying the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$cell->{Val}` for the unformatted raw value instead of `$cell->Value()` for the Excel formatted value.

Comment: I think you have it backwards. Using the code in my answer, replacing `Val` with `_Value` prints `2.46`.